# arrange menu items to fill up blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I want my menu divs to shift according to the markers in the image 1. The second image shows the original menu , as it looks now. How do i shift the `divs` to fill up the space. I tried using `isotope` and `wookmark` but no luck. I could not get it to work. Aby help appretiated.

HTML Markup:

```
<div id="megamenu1" class="megamenu">
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                Web Development</h3>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                News Related</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com/">CNN</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.msnbc.com">MSNBC</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                Technology</h3>
            <ul>

                <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                Web Development</h3>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                News Related</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com/">CNN</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.msnbc.com">MSNBC</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                Technology</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                Technology</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                Technology</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jkmegamenu.definemenu("megaanchor", "megamenu1", "mouseover")
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.megamenu{
position: absolute;
display: none;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: white;
border: 1px solid #f06b24;
border-width: 5px 1px;
padding: 10px;
font: normal 12px Verdana;
z-index: 100;
width:805px;

}

.megamenu .column{
float: left;
width: 180px; /*width of each menu column*/
margin-right: 5px;
}

.megamenu .column ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

.megamenu .column ul li{
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.megamenu .column h3{
background: #e0e0e0;
font: bold 13px Arial;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.megamenu .column ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
}

.megamenu .column ul li a:hover{
color: red;
}
```

This is the link to the menu example http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.shtml
The `.js` is quite long , so i am not pasting it here [.js file link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.js).
[image]

[image: ttt]

Comment: It is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/2v8QK/1/

Comment: @SandeepPattanaik Your fiddle is not working, and it seems you have given me the example from the link i have posted. I am using the menu from that example and its working fine. My issue is with the arrangement of the menu items lists. Some are short some are long , so i want to fill up the blank space by rearranging the items. Kindly read the question again. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if you're looking for a solution to automatically fill out the whitespace (using isotope) or want to have a certain order.

Anyway, both at the same time is not possible.
Isotope will try to put your content as much in order as you placed it, but if it can fill up a small gap with a column found a bit further away it will place it.

**Using isotope** to fill-out whitespace is quite easy:
http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/QfwJa/1/

**Having them in a specific order.**

If you want the content to be shown in a specific order start by placing it in that order in your html.
I noticed you call every "block of content" a column. If you want your content to be in a specific order, first create 4 actual columns, the content inside those columns...

Like so:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByCde

```
<div id="megamenu1" class="megamenu">
<div class="column">
        <div class="content">
        <h3>
            Web Development</h3>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>
            Technology</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</div>

<div class="column">
            <div class="content">
        <h3>
            News Related</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com/">CNN</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.msnbc.com">MSNBC</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h3>
            Technology</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
            <div class="content">
        <h3>
            Technology</h3>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h3>
            News Related</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com/">CNN</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.msnbc.com">MSNBC</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>
            Web Development</h3>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>



    <div class="content">
        <h3>
            Technology</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got it working in a blank page using your code(copied your code)..but the same thing does not work in another page...i have wasted consecutive hours trying to make it work.But no luck yet. Kindly check this page [http://leorbis.com/index112.htm](http://leorbis.com/index112.htm) . Hover on **"Buy">>"Browse By Category">>"Fashion">>"Clothing"** . I t does not take the height. The height is only 20 px. See if you can figure it out. Thanks for your help.I have accepted your answer.

Comment: It's probably because you're applying isotope within a div which, at the moment of initialising, is not shown/has no proper size.